# FIles comparing field by field in PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have two files like

File 1

```
id,sal,location,code
1000,1000,jupiter,F
1001,2000,jupiter,F
1002,3000,jupiter,F
1003,4000,jupiter,F
1004,5000,jupiter,F
```

File 2

```
id,sal,location,code
1000,2000,jupiter,F
1001,2000,jupiter,Z
1002,3000,jupiter,F
1003,4000,jupiter,F
1004,5000,jupiter,F
```

When I compare file1 with file 2, I need a output like

```
1000, sal
1001,code
```

Basically, it should tell me what field is changed from the previous file along with the id.
Can this be done in PIG.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem but the challenging part will the output format as you mentioned. It requires little bit complex logic to get the output format.

I have fixed most of the edge cases but you can check with your input to make sure that it works for all combinations.

**file1:**

```
1000,1000,jupiter,F
1001,2000,jupiter,F
1002,3000,jupiter,F
1003,4000,jupiter,F
1004,5000,jupiter,F
```

**file2:**

```
1000,2000,jupiter,F
1001,2000,jupiter,Z
1002,3000,jupiter,F
1003,4000,jupiter,F
1004,5000,jupiter,F
```

**PigScript:**

```
    A = LOAD 'file1' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id,sal,location,code);
    B = LOAD 'file2' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id,sal,location,code);
    C = JOIN A BY id,B BY id;
    D = FOREACH C GENERATE A::id AS id,((A::sal == B::sal)?'':'sal') AS sal,
                                       ((A::location == B::location)?'':'location') AS location,
                                       ((A::code == B::code)?'':'code') AS code;

    --Remove the common fields between two files    
    E = FILTER D BY NOT (sal=='' AND location=='' AND code=='');

    --The below two lines are used to formatting the output 
    F = FOREACH E GENERATE id,REPLACE(BagToString(TOBAG(sal,location,code),','),'(,,$|,$)','') As finalOutput;
    G = FOREACH F GENERATE id,REPLACE(finalOutput,',,',',');
    DUMP G;
```

**Output:**

```
(1000,sal)
(1001,code)
```